# VB.Net MariaDB Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, mariadb

i want to ask about Inserting data from my SqlDb into MariaDb. My trouble is when i success insert the data, i have double data with same TimeStamp and Status. i explain little about inserting process. Every one AWB have many Status Likes SD,AR,OD,UN,RT,UN,UN and OK. i have insert the data using windows services schedule. i make the schedule every 30 seconds. the trouble is every data that i have ever insert before into MariaDb always drawn again in database so there's a many double data about one AWB in database. how can i deny every data that has been insert before with same status and timestamp  cannot longer go into my MariaDB?

this my 'Select Query and Insert Code'

```
Private Sub getStatus()
    Try
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(DesktopGeneral.koneksiTTM)
        buka2(con)
        Querysend = "Declare @AWB as varchar(50) "
        Querysend += "Select @AWB=Pick_Cust.AWB from Pick_Cust inner join PICKUP_DETIL On Pick_Cust.TrNo=PICKUP_DETIL.TrNo where ComName LIKE '%Lazada%' "
        Querysend += "Select PICKUP_DETIL.AWB,PICKUP_DETIL.RefNo,PICKUP_DETIL.Date,PICKUP_DETIL.time,PICKUP_DETIL.Origin As Station,PICKUP_DETIL.CP2 As Status,'' as Recipient,'' as Relation,'' as Remarks,PICKUP_DETIL.Login,'' as ReasonCode,'' as ReasonNote,'Data Entry' as Comment from PICKUP_DETIL "
        Querysend += "inner join RECEIVED r on PICKUP_DETIL.AWB=r.AWB where pickup_Detil.AWB=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select PICKUP_DETIL.AWB,PICKUP_DETIL.RefNo,PICKUP_DETIL.PUdate as Date,PICKUP_DETIL.PUtime as Time,PICKUP_DETIL.Origin as Station,PICKUP_DETIL.CP as Status,'' as Recipient,'' as Relation,'' as Remarks, c.CouName,'' as ReasonCode,'' as ReasonNote,'Pick-Up' as Comment from PICKUP_DETIL "
        Querysend += "inner join COURIER c on PICKUP_DETIL.Pic=c.CouRoute where AWB=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select BABY.AWB,p.RefNo,BABY.DATE,BABY.TIME,BABY.STN as Station,BABY.CP as Status,'' as Recipient,'' as Relation,BABY.BABY as Remarks,BABY.LOGIN,'' as ReasonCode,'' as ReasonNote,'Sotir Departement/Destination' as Comment from BABY "
        Querysend += "inner join PICKUP_DETIL p on BABY.AWB=p.AWB where baby.AWB=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select ARRIVAL.Code,p.RefNo,CONVERT(char(10),arrival.Date,120) as Date,CONVERT(char(5),arrival.Date,114) as Time,STN as Station,arrival.CP as Status,'' as Recipient,'' as  Relation,'' as Remarks, arrival.PIC,'' as ReasonCode,'' as ReasonNote,'Arrival at Destination HUB' as Comment from ARRIVAL "
        Querysend += "inner join PICKUP_DETIL p on ARRIVAL.Code=p.AWB where code=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select DELIVERY.AWB,p.RefNo,CONVERT(char(10),delivery.Date,120) as Date,CONVERT(char(5),delivery.Date,114) as Time, STN as Station,delivery.CP as Status,'' as Recipient,'' as Relation,'Kurir:' +COURIER.CouName + '.Note:'+Note + ' Cycle:'+CYCLE as Remarks,delivery.PIC,'' as ReasonCode,'' as ReasonNote,'On Delivery' as Comment from Delivery "
        Querysend += "inner join COURIER on DELIVERY.CouRoute=COURIER.CouRoute inner join PICKUP_DETIL p on DELIVERY.AWB=p.AWB where delivery.AWB=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select UNDELIVERED.AWB,pd.RefNo,CONVERT(char(10),undelivered.date,120) as Date,CONVERT(char(5),undelivered.date,114) as Time,STN as Station,undelivered.CP as Status,'' as Recipient,'' as Relation,Note+'>' as Remarks,c.CouName,Other as ReasonCode,a.Remarks as ReasonNote,'Undelivered' as Comment from UNDELIVERED "
        Querysend += "inner join COURIER c on UNDELIVERED.PIC=c.CouRoute inner join RMK_RET a on UNDELIVERED.Other=a.Code inner join PICKUP_DETIL pd on UNDELIVERED.AWB=pd.AWB where undelivered.AWB=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select RECEIVED.AWB,pd.RefNo,CONVERT(char(10),received.Date,120) as Date,CONVERT(char(5),received.Date,114) as Time,STN as Station,received.CP as Status,Recipient as Recipient,Relation as Relation,Note as Remarks,received.PIC,'' as ReasonCode,'' as ReasonNote,'Delivery Success' as Comment from RECEIVED "
        Querysend += "inner join PICKUP_DETIL pd on RECEIVED.AWB=pd.AWB where received.AWB=@AWB "
        Querysend += "union "
        Querysend += "Select [RETURN].AWB,pd.RefNo,CONVERT(char(10),[return].date,120) as Date,CONVERT(char(5),[return].date,114) as Time,STN as Station,[return].CP as Status,'' as Recipient,'' as Relation,Note as Remarks,[return].PIC,returnCode as ReasonCode,a.Remarks as ReasonNote,'Return Shipper' as Comment from [RETURN] "
        Querysend += "inner join RMK_RET a on [RETURN].returnCode=a.Code inner join PICKUP_DETIL pd on [RETURN].AWB=pd.AWB where [return].AWB=@AWB "
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Querysend, con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "joe")
        tutup2(con)

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(DesktopGeneral.koneksiAPI)
            buka(cn)
            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                Querysend = "Insert into api_status(AWB,TrackingNumber,Status,TimeStamp,Comment,Station,Recipient,Relation,ReasonCode,ReasonNote,Attempt,Username,RequestID,Flag) "
                Querysend += "VALUES(@AWB,@TrackingNumber,@Status,@TimeStamp,@Comment,@Station,@Recipient,@Relation,@ReasonCode,@ReasonNote,@Attempt,@Username,@RequestID,@Flag) "
                Dim mycmd As New MySqlCommand(Querysend, cn)
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("AWB", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("AWB").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("TrackingNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Refno").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Status", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Status").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("TimeStamp", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = CDate(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Date").ToString).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & " " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Time").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Comment", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Comment").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Station", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Station").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Recipient", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Recipient").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Relation", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Relation").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("ReasonCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ReasonCode").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("ReasonNote", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ReasonNote").ToString
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Attempt", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = 1
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Joe"
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("RequestID", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ""
                mycmd.Parameters.Add("Flag", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = 0
                mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                mycmd.Dispose()
            Next
            tutup(cn)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim err As String
        err = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please Help. Thank You before :)

Comment: Looks like you are running the same SELECT query every 30 seconds, so it will return the same data and insert the same data in the target db again and again.

Comment: Thank for response @Chetan. i put the settings time in my config file. so it automatically pull the data to my MariaDB. So, how can i ignore the data with the same status and timestamp in order not longer pull to my MariaDB? any suggest with code?

Comment: `"Select @AWB=Pick_Cust.AWB from Pick_Cust inner join PICKUP_DETIL On Pick_Cust.TrNo=PICKUP_DETIL.TrNo where ComName LIKE '%Lazada%' "` will always return the same single record. Are you trying to retrieve the most recently inserted record from that table? Your requirement is not really clear - what is an AWB and what records are you trying to select?

Comment: You need to filter the data. You need to keep track of until what point, such as timestamp,  the data is insterted in MariaDB and store that information. So that next time you select data from that point only. Like you select 1000 rows for certain timestamp. Store the timestamp of the last row. Use that timestamp in next run and so on. If you can provide some details about your data and selection criteria the it will be easy to provide specific solution.

Comment: @ADyson thanks man, you're right about the query but it will always select the AWB with Customer Lazada. I just take the status of Customer Lazada and transfer it into my MariaDB. i just want to know how to make the data doesn't insert again and again with One AWB.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya if i can insert image in this comment, i will post the selection data and inserting table data. i'm still confusing how to do that. can you explain me with code?

Comment: If you want to avoid repeated inserts, then only ever run the query once! But I assume that isn't the intention. You want to select a different row each time the query runs, right? If so, what is the rule by which you must select it? Most recent? After some point in time? You realise, I assume, it will only ever select 1 row at a time?

Comment: @ADyson you're right about that. but when i make it automatically using windows services it will get the data that ever insert before. i want if the AWB with Status and TimeStamp that ever insert previously cannot be insert again in my MariaDB. i have explain above that One AWB have many status likes SD,AR,OD,RT,UN,UN,OK. So, if they are ever insert previously it cannot insert again when windows services is running in next 30seconds.

Comment: so basically you want to select the 1st record from from Cust.AWB where there is no record in api_status with a matching timestamp and status? You could do it with some sort of `NOT IN` query, like what pream has suggested in their answer, probably. But an easier solution might be to add a "status_logged" boolean field into your Pick_Cust or PICKUP_DETIL table (whichever is appropriate, it's hard to be certain) to mark that row as processed. You can update it after the insert completes. Then next time you can select the first row where "status_logged" is false.

Comment: Yeah you're right @ADyson but i'm still confuse to do in code. can you explain it with code? or just edited my code above so i can see the different.

Comment: @Joinnes, did you try linking the MariaDB server as i suggested in the answer? if you are successful in linking the server then its a piece of cake to just add except statement

Comment: and refer this [link](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server/oracle-linked-server) for usage example of sp_addlinkedserver to create linked server

Answer (score 0):

Use except statement at the last in the Querysend string like

```
except 
select AWB,TrackingNumber,Station,Status,CONVERT(char(10),TimeStamp,120) as
Date,CONVERT(char(5),TimeStamp,114) as Time,Station,Status,Recipient,Relation,
ReasonCode,ReasonNote,Comment from [MariaDb].[dbo].[api_status] where AWB=@AWB
```

You can link the server using sp_addlinkedserver() if it is from a different server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Example:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ]   
[ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]  
[ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ]   
[ , [ @location= ] 'location' ]   
[ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ]   
[ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]
```

then

```
to use your MariaDb Table [server].[MariaDb].[dbo].[api_status]
```

Comment: Hi @Pream thanks for your response. So, i have to put the except in last of the QuerySend? it has a different database man. in select query on QuerySend is from SqlDB. how it could be select from api_status while api_status is MariaDB. Can you explain me?

Comment: hi @Joinnes Yeah, if they are in the same server, you can just use MariaDb.dbo.api_status  and SqlDb.dbo.PICKUP_DETIL

Comment: but they are different database man. how to do that? can you edit the above code, so i can see the result.

Comment: @Joinnes, Please check the answer now

Comment: @Joinnes give an example data for the date, time and time stamp values

Comment: for TimeStamp it's like '2016-12-15 09:52:00'. So every AWB have each timestamp from AR(Arrival) -> OD(OnDelivery) -> RT(Return) -> UN(Undelivered) -> OK(Success). with my code above i have pull all Status from Specific Customer with windows services. i got the problem when inserting all data. data that ever insert previously will get entry when the services running next according the time (every 30 seconds). how to fix it man?

Comment: @Joinnes why do you want these columns "Note as Remarks and [something].PIC" when you are not using them in insert statement?
remove those columns and use the except statement as in the edited answer